# Grease Pencil - preview ignores canvas settings?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, grease-pencil, clipping

When previewing grease pencil (before pen release), the Origin/3D Cursor/Ortho drawing planes do not render properly. It looks like the preview is stuck on "View" but renders correctly on pen release. In my GIF you can see the strokes clipping, but appear correct after pen release. Can this be fixed?

[GIF Link](https://media1.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExZ2tmbnJzN3kzbTR4eHFzOGlibTM5MHl5ODk0ZHlsNmd5bngxc3owNSZlcD12MV9pbnRlcm5hbF9naWZfYnlfaWQmY3Q9Zw/zRrJqOwLR4h36cdgCe/giphy.gif)

[image: While Drawing]
[image: After Pen Release]

Comment: This Q&A site is run by volunteers. There are no Blender developers here and no-one here has any association with the Blender Foundation. If you think this is a bug you should report it via Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu.  Please add your image directly into your question rather than making folks use a link which may not exist in future. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Comment: Updated with Before and After images. I don't know if this is a bug, that's why I'm asking if anyone else has this easily repro'd issue. I've also reported this on bug report.

Comment: I've never used grease pencil, but have you tried changing the Clip Start and End settings on the N-panel View menu?

Comment: Unfortunately any clip plane adjustments don't affect it. Someone on the collaborator forum said Grease Pencil 3.0 is broken so... TBD!

Comment: You haven't given any indication of what Blender version you are using, but 3.6 is due for release next week so it may be fixed with any luck.